# using the modified bessel functions in matlab and gsl

Tags: c, matlab, filter, gsl, bessel-functions

I am trying to make a kaiser window for a audio signal using both Matlab and c.I have been looking at Matlab and gnu scientific library documentation to understand how to use a modified bessel function of first kind and 0th order, but I still have some questions:

- It seems that GSL does not accept a 0 order bessel function, I don't understand the documentation on this point.
- I don't know if I should use a regular or irregular function. What are their differences? Matlab do not have that.
- which is the fastest method to filter the signal: time domain or frequency domain?
- how to filter the signal on the frequency domain?

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer to the last three points. (Warning : I am french and my english isn't great...)

1) When you consider the Fourier transform of a signal multiplied by a specific window, in the spectral domain, you convolute the original spectrum of the signal by the spectrum of your window. In an ideal mathematical world, you would love to have a Dirac since it's convolution would only shift the signal. But to get a Dirac in the frequency you would need a periodic signal in the time domain which isn't defined on a compact (i.e. finite like your sound record) support. And this is too bad because there is a theorem (Paley-Wiener's corollary) that states that if your time-domain support is compact your frequency-domain support is not bounded and the decreasing behaviour of the Fourier transform increase with the regularity of the signal (i.e. window in our case). Great then ! All we have to chose is a nice regular (smooth ?) window. Unfortunately, to get a really smooth window, we have to narrow it (wide smooth windows exist but have other drawbacks dues to their derived function...its like too large constants ahead appealing algorithmic complexity) and it's spectrum will be wider (for the same reason invoked in the theorem). But you (and Obama) believe in compromise to face the (Pontryagin) duality, don't you ? The gaussian is a great compromise since its Fourier transform is a gaussian too (sum of random variables ? convolution ? +,x-morphism in the complex plane...every thing is linked but its a too long non-linear story to be told here). Therefore a lot of window tend to look like a gaussian.

Here is a bunch of windows and spectrums stolen to my speech processing teacher :

[image]

[image]

2) It's a pure mathematical duality, so it depends of what you mean by fiter. Does applying a Sobel filter into the frequency-domain make any sense ? (in fact it may...)

3) Again, it depends of what you mean by filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer (1) and (2):

(1) You can program the zeroth order Bessel functions yourself (spherical or not) by consulting a handbook on mathematical functions such as Abramowitz and Stegun, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, or the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (http://dlmf.nist.gov/).

(2) By regular and irregular, I presume you mean regular or modified Bessel functions. Bessel functions are solutions to the three-dimensional heat equation posed in cylindrical coordinates. Your boundary conditions determine your use of regular or modified Bessel functions. For nice discussions about regular and modified Bessel functions, I suggest reading The Conduction of Heat in Solids by Carslaw and Jaeger and Boundary Value Problems of Heat Conduction by M. Necati Ozisik. You can also try for difficult problems Classical Electrodynamics by John David Jackson.

How are the regular and modified Bessel functions different? The regular J Bessel function is somewhat oscillatory in nature (see a nice old book like Jahnke, Emde, and Losch for hand-drawn Bessel function graphs, a lost art form if you ask me) whereas I and K are single-valued.

I can't really help you much on (3) and (4), as I'm not much an electrical engineer (although I would like to learn more!).